# How to use fn-key (function keys) with an external keyboard that has no fn-key?

Tags: macos, keyboard, macbook-pro

I am using Lion on a late 2009 13 inch MacBook, with external monitor and an external [Apple Keyboard with numeric keypad - German (MB110D/B)](http://store.apple.com/uk/product/MB110D/B/apple-keyboard-with-numeric-keypad) while keeping the MacBook lid closed.

Some of the applications I run use the F-keys. This works fine for <kbd>F5</kbd> and <kbd>F6</kbd> but the other key are used for things like muting and so on.

There is an option in the preferences to use the <kbd>fn</kbd>-key in combination with the F-key. Unfortunately the keyboard I am using has no <kbd>fn</kbd>-key. Any ideas?

Comment: The question has already been answered before:
http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24758/how-do-i-map-a-key-on-the-a1048-109-key-keyboard-to-provide-an-fn-button